# ash shell command not running while building image but in the container it works fine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a `docker-compose.yml` containing like this:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
        n2:
            build: .
            restart: always
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

And `Dockerfile` like this:

```
from nginx:stable-alpine

add cm.ash /root
run chmod +x /root/cm.ash
run /root/cm.ash
```

And this is `cm.ash` commands:

```
#!/bin/ash
nginx -s reload
```

The issue is when I run docker-compose to build, I get this error:

> 2021/03/07 04:18:35 [notice] 8#8: signal process started 2021/03/07

> 04:18:35 [error] 8#8: open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such

> file or directory) nginx: [error] open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed

> (2: No such file or directory) The command '/bin/sh -c /root/cm.ash'

> returned a non-zero code: 1

While if I comment lines `add cm.ash /root`, `run chmod +x /root/cm.ash` and `run /root/cm.ash` in `Dockerfile`, and then I `exec` container with `ash` then run command `nginx -s reload`, it works fine.

Why does this happen and what is the reason of this behavior?

I have seen similar behavior between `bash` and `dash`, that I resolve it by adding a `bash` file into the image to run commands on behalf of bash shell to get my results and it works fine, but I'm not sure about the reason of this behavior in `dash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During build there is no `nginx` daemon running in the build container, so you can not connect to the daemon and tell him to `reload`.

This also means that you don't need to reload since nothing is loaded at this point.

When you start container from the final image, than the daemon (which is the entry point for the `ngingx` image, will start and you will be able to connect to the `PID` of the running instance to tell it to reload.

Comment: Great, thanks for the details. The reason is I'm adding some `.conf` and SSL files to the container and I think I need to reload the daemon. Then, what should I do for this?

Comment: nothing, the config files will be loaded when you start the new container. It's same like shutting down `ngingx` and changing the configuration. There is nothing to do but to start `ngingx`